# Simple Looking Problem in Geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

**The problem**

Given the following figure

[image]

determine $x$.

**My solution(s):**

There are many possibilities to use similarities and the Pythagorean resulting more or less complicated systems of equations.

**The simplest solution** I could come up with  was the following.

Because of the similarity of $AEF$ and $FCD$, we may say that  $u=1/x$.

Based on the Pythagorean we have that
 $$(1+x)^2+(1+1/x)^2=100.$$

This equation has two positive real solutions. One of them is:
$$x=\frac12\left(-1+\sqrt{101}+\sqrt{98-2\sqrt{101}}\right)\approx 8.937.$$ The other one is $\frac1{8.937}.$

(http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+(1%2Bx)%5E2%2B(1%2B1%2Fx)%5E2%3D100)

---

**The question**

The source of the problem above is an old (Hungarian) high scholl level problem book. So, I suspect that there must be a simpler solution not requiring the roots of a fourth order equations. Please, either prove that there is no simpler solution or show one.

Comment: Let $y=x+1/x$. Solve $y$ first, which is doable by formula of roots of quadratic equations.

Comment: Do you mean that I should try the following two substitutions: $x_{1,2}=\frac{y\pm \sqrt{y^2-4}}2 ?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write down my thoughts here. If not satisfying you requirements, please inform me and I would delete this.

When solving 
$$
(1+x)^2 + \left(1 + \frac 1x\right)^2 = 100,
$$
we first expand it to
$$
x^2 + \frac 1{x^2} + 2 + 2x +\frac 2x = 100,
$$
then notice that 
$$
x^2 +\frac 1{x^2} + 2 = \left(x + \frac 1x\right)^2, 
$$
we let $y = x + 1/x$, then 
$$
y^2 + 2y = 100,
$$
which is easily solvable by the roots formula of quadratic equations. Then all  knowledge we used is taught before college, and the question could be used as a high school level geometry exercise.

Comment: Shame on me. Thank you. This is clear.

Comment: You are welcome. No shame here. Sometimes we may neglect something which is totally not a big deal.